# Using Server Cache or Plugin when using Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Which is better? To have php cache through my server or installing a cache plugin (wordpress).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synergy is the key to making a site load quickly. Browser Cache, Compressed Images and loading Java Script last are probably the most advantageous, will yield the biggest return for your time.

**W3 Total Cache** is a plug in trusted for improving the performance of many WordPress sites. You will need to spend some time learning about the plugin's features but it will defiantly get you going in the right direction.

However, I would start with [**Google's Page Speed Insights**](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/#) to give yourself a baseline as you make changes via W3 Total Cache.